# How to always re-generate version header file when underlying VERSION text file changes using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I maintain a C++ framework/library that uses CMake as its build system. The framework's version is reflected in a file called `VERSION` (as in many open source libraries).

I would like to generate a C++ header file with a version string, using `VERSION` as input. I also want this to happen during a re-build, not just when *recreating project files*. It would be desirable if `VERSION` was a dependency so the header file is created only when `VERSION` has changed.

I am familiar with the technique using the `file()` command in CMake to read the contests of `VERSION`, e.g.

```
file(STRINGS "VERSION" FRAMEWORK_VERSION)
```

And then generating a file using the `configure_file` command, e.g.:

```
configure_file(version.h.in version.h)
```

But this only generates the header file during the generation of project files. If the `VERSION` file is changed, the version header file will not be re-generated when re-building (i.e. running `cmake --build .`).

I know I can use like a Python script run as a CMake macro and always create the version header during the build, but I find it a bit annoying.

What is the best practice here?

Isn't it possible to solve this by only using CMake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One CMake-only solution is to wrap the commands you suggested in a custom target to run a CMake script. If you make your library *depend* on the custom target, it will behave per the following:

- Generates `version.h` at compile-time, before building your library.
- Only re-generates `version.h` if its contents will change (new version number or new template file, `version.h.in`)

The script (let's say `VersionHeader.cmake`) for the custom target will read the version number from the `VERSION` file, and generate a new `version.h` file if necessary. The script can look like this:

```
file(STRINGS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/VERSION" FRAMEWORK_VERSION)
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/version.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/version.h @ONLY)
```

Then, in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, define a custom target to [run a script](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script):

```
add_custom_target(VersionHeader
  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VersionHeader.cmake
)
add_dependencies(MyFrameworkLib VersionHeader)
```

Comment: For some reason `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/VERSION` evaluates to my build/binary directory, `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VERSION` gets it right though. Strange.

Comment: I don't know if this is best practice but it is good enough for me.